# use of substr or slice or substring inside <tmpl_var xxx>

Tags: javascript, html

I am receiving a variable with string value:

```
xxx = Saturday 16 june 15:00.
```

I need to display it on webpage using like:

```
<tmpl_var xxx>
```

This works fine for to display whole string. But I need to display only **15:00**. I was trying like:

```
<tmpl_var substring(xxx.length - 5)>
```

But it is not working. Any suggestion?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it a bit readable? tmpl_var.substring(x,y) would be the correct syntax for substring. Where do you get the Date from? Is it being fetched from the backend? Or are you creating it with javascript right away? If so, the Date object has methods to display only the hh:mm

Comment: can you some solid code and what you want to acheive clearly. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: <div class="form-text-top-space">
            <label>Return</label>
            <h4><tmpl_var rettime></h4>
          </div>

Comment: @javed Read how to ask the question. Community is to help others not be adamant.

Comment: this is an html file, not javascript. How to use substring inside element

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small function for you. If you need to with dates/times a lot then consider using some established libraries like [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com) or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org).

```
function getTime(timeStr) {
    let d = new Date(timeStr);
    let hours = String(d.getHours());
    let minutes = String(d.getMinutes());

    if (hours.length === 1) {
        hours = "0" + hours
    }

    if (minutes.length === 1) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes
    }

    return hours + ":" + minutes;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I might have misinterpreted OP's question btw

Comment: thanks for your response, but I dont have possibility to trigger the getTime function. What I need is like: <tmpl_var substring(xxx.length - 5)>

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved and the solution is:

```
<tmpl_var expr="substr(arrtime, (length(arrtime)-5))">
```